# Travis-CI error with: clang: error: no such file or directory:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration, travis-ci

My .travis.yml file:

```
language: objective-c

osx_image: xcode7.2

before_install:
   - rvm use system
   - sudo gem install cocoapods -v '0.39.0'  

script: 
   xctool -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme ProjectName build -sdk iphonesimulator
```

It looks ok. However, I've got this error while Travis is running.

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/travis/build/MyName/ProjectFolder/ViewControllers/CCPViewController.m'
>   clang: error: no input files
>   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
>
> 2 errored, 0 warning (3517 ms)
>   Failures:
>   0) Compile /Users/travis/build/MyName/ProjectFolder/ViewControllers/CCPViewController.m
>   ** BUILD FAILED ** (20966 ms)

It looks like it is not in the project, but it is there. 
It is supposed to be red because is not there, but it is black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the Files are not missing (red) inside the project they are not really there.

To solve the problem git clone the repo in another place. Open the new copy of the project, open the folder and your classes will be red.

[image]

This classes did not exist in GitHub. Probably they were added wrongly inside the project. Do it properly now.

I was dragging a folder with the 2 classes, for some reason the folder name was not accepted by Xcode. I changed the name (from Pods to Pod) of the Folder and then Xcode accepted the classes. Finally the classes were in the `git add .`.

[image]

Commit and push and now Travis is working without problem.

It looks like the error is caused because I has 2 folders named `Pods`. My one and the one created by Cocoapods. It is a nonsense.

[I also wrote a post in my blog about Travis-CI.](https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/add-travis-ci-to-your-coding-challenge/)